# upload images without selecting a file in codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter

Hi i have this upload images in codeigniter and it runs well in saving the file to the images folder then to the database. My problem is i want that when im not selecting a file on it and my current image will retain cause this is for the edit profile page. Im not setting any validations on any textbox. only for uploading the images. when im about to upload a non image type like .doc .exe .flv or not an image it validates to this one "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." and i want that when im not changing the image it will retain the current image. 
here my code below

```
 $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/uploads/';
      // set the filter image types
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
      $config['max_size'] = '9000';
      $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      $this->upload->initialize($config);
      $this->upload->set_allowed_types($config['allowed_types']);
      $data['upload_data'] = '';

      //if not successful, set the error message
      if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
        $data =  $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 1); 
        redirect('profile/edit/id/'.$ids, $data);

       }else{ //else, set the success message        
        $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();

        $uploadSuccess = $data['upload_data'];

        $raw_name = $uploadSuccess['file_name'];

        $file_name = $raw_name;
        //print_r($file_name);exit;
        $image_path = 'assets/uploads/' .$file_name;
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] =  $image_path;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 150;
        $config['height'] = 110;
        //$config['quality'] = '80%'; 

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

        $this->image_lib->resize($image_path);
        $this->image_lib->clear();
      }
```

with this line of code

```
!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')
```

when im uploading a non image this will validate with this line of code too. and will work

```
$data =  $this->upload->display_errors();
```

and my views

```
 <?php if($this->session->flashdata('error')): ?>
          <div class="alert alert-success">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>
            <p >The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.</p>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I want that when im not selecting a file it will retain my curent photo in my edit page
can someone help me figured this thing out??Any help is muchly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

before uploading image code or if you are using a function for image upload, before it you have to set a condition, if image available then that code should be run. For example:

```
if(isset($_FILES['photo']['name'])){
  // image upload code here or call upload function
}
```

This may be help you.

Comment: can you broaden you thoughts?

Comment: have you add that check?, i think when you submit your form, either you selected the image or not, image upload code run, so this condition will check if image exist then image upload code run otherwise skip. because when there is no image selected then your code replace the existing image with empty one in db not in folder, so in edit case you also have to delete existing image against that id both in db and folder.

Comment: where will i add your code? can you edit you answer based on my code above?

Comment: i know your code will run but i want a clear answer that suits my code above